# How to parse input with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have the list of docker images in json, for example:

```
{
  "name": "chart1",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "appVersion": "1.1.0",
  "dependencies": [
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "version": "10000.1.wew2133"
   },
   {
    "name": "name2",
    "version": "10001.1.wew2133"
   }
  ]
}
```

I need to convert this to list:

```
name1:10000.1.wew2133
name2:10001.1.wew2133
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Added full JSON

Answer (score 1):

Use [`join(":")`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example61):

```
jq --raw-output '.dependencies[] | join(":")'
```

```
name1:10000.1.wew2133
name2:10001.1.wew2133
```

[JQPlay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/FWETu0x_T2)